# How to provide separate classes for iPhone + iPad in one universal build?

Tags: iphone, ipad

Problem: In my iPhone app code, I'm positioning and animating a lot of views programmatically. For the iPad, I want to provide a completely different user interface, but also programmatically. I don't like to use Xib files. How can I make different views and view controllers and load these depending on if it's an iPad or an iPhone? What's the cleanest way?

Comment: I won't read your question before you accept some answers to your questions.

Comment: @Jacob What question? I have 1 unaccepted question.

Comment: Accepted all good answers. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to specify the device identifier, you can do that by adding the string "~iphone" or "~ipad". So for a view controller this would be; "MyViewController~iphone.m" and for the iPad "MyViewController~ipad.m"

Answer (score 1):

In addition, if you are having compilation problems because you are programatically creating classes only available to iOS 3.2 and above you can use code like this:

```
Class popClass = NSClassFromString(@"UIPopoverController");
if(popClass) {
    id infoPop = [[popClass alloc] initWithContentViewController:popViewController];
    [infoPop presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(20, 70, 10, 10) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:4 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: You should use `UIUserInterfaceIdiom` instead.

Comment: That will detect if the code should be run, but it won't help during compilation if your target is pre-3.2.  It could certainly replace the test but NSCLassFromString would still be needed to create a class the target device might not know about.